# Monitoring Connectivity above Lollipop

Tags: java, android, android-livedata

After struggling with many deprecated and not working solution for monitoring connectivity. Here is my single-file implementation to monitor connectivity above Android 21+ and will work upto android 10.
the livedata returns the boolean value of connectivity status. So that you can easily get notified whenever there is any changes in connectivity status.

Hope it will help someone too!!

source-> https://gist.github.com/ideepeshtiwari/dfb2ed4ebddd59ee57b258b408654670

```
public class ConnectivityListener extends LiveData<Boolean> {

    private ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;

    public ConnectivityListener(Application context) {

        connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) 
context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    }
    private ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback callback = new 
ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {
            super.onAvailable(network);
            postValue(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLost(@NonNull Network network) {
            super.onLost(network);
            postValue(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUnavailable() {
            super.onUnavailable();
            postValue(false);
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onActive() {
        super.onActive();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            NetworkCapabilities capabilities =     connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
            if (capabilities != null) {
                boolean isConnected = capabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET);
                postValue(isConnected);
            }
        } else {
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            boolean isConnected = networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
            postValue(isConnected);
        }

        NetworkRequest.Builder builder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(callback);
        } else {
            connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(builder.build(), callback);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInactive() {
        super.onInactive();
        connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(callback);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your requirement ?

Comment: @Quicklearner nothing just trying to help others who might face this issue.

Comment: that should be on github dear

Comment: Actually it could be presented on StackOverflow as a question with an accepted answer. It's possible to answer your own questions on StackOverflow. It's a nice way to share knowledge with the community.